# How to make sure spinners fit in the screen size?

Tags: android

With this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/user_pro_main_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        [ ... ]

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/PersonalInfoGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/rowName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/layout_name"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/rowUploadPhotos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textUploadPhotos"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/layout_upload_photos"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinUploadPhotos"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/upload_photos_num_array" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/rowInterest"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textInterest"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/layout_interest"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinInterest"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/rowAge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textAge"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/layout_age"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinAge"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/rowFirstChat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textFirstChat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/layout_first_sex_rel"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <DatePicker
                    android:id="@+id/firstChatDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </TableRow>
```

I get this:

[image]

As you can see on the simulator screen capture attached, spinners are too large, and they won't fit in the screen real estate. 
On the real device, the behavior is identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the TableRow that contains your spinner, replace it with a linearlayout (horizontal orientation) and give layout_weight for the textview (60) and spinner(40).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works! But, what about the datepicker? I do the same with it, but it's very big.

Comment: Yes, you can use the same technique i described. But I suggest you make it a dialog that pops up where the user selects the date. This will save you the space and make your UI relaxed.

Comment: I have used the same technique with it.

Comment: @VansFannel have you varied the weight correctly? Give is a less weight for Date Picker.